# How can i implement ntru cryptography algorithm in java?

Tags: java, cryptography, ntruencrypt

As it is shown in few survey that ntru cryptography is an advance and efficient algorithm for wireless sensor network , so i want to implement this algorithm in java. I also want to calculate it speed of encryption and decryption.

Please help me with the process.. :)

Comment: "How can i implement ntru cryptography algorithm in java?" - One approach is writing code.

Comment: Programm as well as the speed of it ? Have you started writing code ?

Comment: There are already existing java implementations: [Tim Tim Buktu's NTRU](http://tbuktu.github.io/ntru/ntru12.html) and I believe the official implementation supports java as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing a crypto algorithm is hard. You should not attempt it unless you have significant experience and expertise in the field of cryptography. Even though you might come up with something that passes the published test cases, an inexperienced programmer may produce an implementation that is vulnerable attack through other channels, such as timing etc.

[This essay from Bruce Schneier](https://www.schneier.com/essay-028.html) is an interesting read.

In short, find an existing implementation that is widely known, used and trusted. It will have had a lot of scrutinisation and testing and is much more likely to be secure than anything you could do yourself.